# Oracle: Delete older records keeping newest n records for users based on Created_On timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in Oracle 11g with multiple records for different users, I want to delete excess records which are older, from the table and keep only 5 newest records for particular users.

Example:
Consider the following table screenshot having multiple records for user "JACK", "ANGEL", "MACK" I have to only keep 5 records(rows) for every users which are new based on column "CREATED_ON" and delete the older ones.

[image: Demo Table]

Can anybody provide me with a sample Oracle query to execute the above scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete from testp 
        where id in 
        (    select id
             from
             ( 
                  select id, row_number() over ( 
                          partition by name order by created_on desc ) rn
                  from testp)
              where rn > 5
         )
```

Assumes:

1. Table is called testp in this example.
2. ID is a PK on the record.